# Better Efficiency for assembling integers from bytes

Tags: c#

My application receives data from a serial port, which is send in packets. The packets are defined as following

```
1 byte  - Identifier
2 bytes - lenght of data
n bytes - data 
1 bytes - Checksum
```

For example if the length is specified as `508` there will be `508` bytes, which would be `127` `uint32_t` values.

Currently I use the following code to assemble the `uint32_t` values from the data that is sent in bytes:

```
private UInt32[] number_array = new UInt32[16384];

private void decodePacket(int startpos, byte[] data, int lenght)
{
    /* Starting position */
    int pos = startpos;

    for(int i=0; i<lenght; i++)
    {
        /* Convert 4 bytes to one uint32_t value */
        int value = data[i] | data[i + 1]<<8 | data[i + 2]<<16 | data[i + 3]<<24;
            
        /* Write to array */
        number_array[pos] = Convert.ToUInt32(value);

        /* Advance i by 4 (bytes */
        i += 4;

        /* Advance pos */
        pos++;
    }
}
```

It does work fine, but I'm thinking it's very inefficient. There are usually 16384 uint32_t values to process, so this function is called a lot of times.

Is there a *more efficient / faster* way to do this?

Comment: [BitConverter.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_BitConverter_ToInt32_System_Byte___System_Int32_)

Comment: [BitConverter.ToUInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint32?view=net-5.0) Even better as you won't have to convert an `int` to a `uint` either.

Comment: In addition to `BitConverter` consider using contiguous blocks of memory to reduce cache misses and speed up the actual execution of the arrays. You would use [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-5.0) for this.

Comment: Another possibility, depending on the data that is being sent in the packets. Consider analyzing the data packets that get received, and if you notice boiler plate information(information that is always sent but not always used), consider truncating(or ignoring) that information and not processing it to save time.

Comment: Be careful with the [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint32?view=net-5.0) though: The order of bytes in the array must reflect the endianness of the computer system's architecture.

Comment: "I'm thinking it's very inefficient" - as ever with performance, don't guess. Set yourself concrete requirements, and measure. Do you have those requirements at the moment, and well-written benchmarks? How close is your current code to meeting those requirements, and can you share the benchmarks?

Comment: You appear to be incrementing i by 5 each time around the loop??

Comment: You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder?view=net-5.0 to flip the byte order, if required.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this simple code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[]
    {
        1, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 5
    };

    byte id = data[0];
    byte[] len = new byte[4];
    Array.Copy(data, 1, len, 0, 2);

    int dataLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(len, 0);

    byte[] dataRead = new byte[dataLen];
    Array.Copy(data, 3, dataRead, 0, dataLen);

    byte checksum = data[data.Length - 1];

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Now, first you get identifier that is on the first pos.
Next, you get length of the data. You have to create 4 byte array to copy values from data array to this new array. It should be 4 bytes, because you would like to convert those bytes into Int32. You could have this array 2 bytes length and convert it to Int16, but Int32 should have better performance.

So, when you have length data in this len array, you can convert those values into Int32. But be careful of endianes. It may be different.

At the end you create an array that will contain all the REAL data. And then copy the real data to new array.

This solution should be faster than yours. But... Be careful of endianess.

Comment: I strongly doubt that this solution would be more efficient than the original. There is absolutely no need to allocate the `len` array and copy the bytes over. Use that second parameter you have in BitConverter.ToInt32.

Comment: Of course there is a need. BitConverter.ToInt32 expects 4 byte array. Here, length is 2 byte long. Anyway, why downvote? It will be more efficient because there are no loops nor iterations. Just simple memory copies.

Comment: @AdamJachocki your code doesn't convert the data bytes to `int`s, which is what OP asked for a more efficient way. You're just copying the bytes from one array to another.

Comment: I don't know why you think that [BitConverter.ToUInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint32?view=net-5.0) expects a 4 byte array. That is absolutely not the case. In fact, that's why there is the second parameter: to indicate where in a much longer array you want to read.

Comment: Oh, and to read the two-byte integer, use [BitConverter.ToUInt16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint16?view=net-5.0) (or manual bit shifting).

Comment: I am using ToInt32, not UInt32. Just read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-5.0 You can also try to set there array that is less than 4 bytes length and see what happens. My code IS faster because this is just simple memory operations instead of looping. OP didn't ask for converting data bytes to int, this would be senseless as data can be really long :| If you don't believe that my was is more efficient, just measure it and come back.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the best possible way using C#

```
private void decodePacket(int startpos, byte[] data, int lenght)
{
    /* Starting position */
    int pos = startpos;

    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i += 4)
    {
        /* Convert 4 bytes to one uint32_t value */
        int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, i);

        /* Write to array */
        number_array[pos] = Convert.ToUInt32(value);

        /* Advance pos */
        pos++;
    }
}
```

This is same code as in question but with two changes.

1. Index `i` was being incremented at two places which was resulting in increments of `5` instead of `4`. Changed it to just one increment of `4`.
2. Use of `BitConveter` instead of bitwise logic. Although it might not provide any significant performance boost. It is better to use `BitConverter` for platform independence.

**UPDATE**

In case your bytes are stored at 32-bit aligned memory addresses `BitConverter` provides you with maximum performance conversion. But in C# you cannot guarantee memory location alignment. In that case bit shifting is the only way.

In case of bit shifting `BitConverter` also uses same logic for *little endian* systems as shown in question. But, it can help keeping your code platform independent by using another bit shifting pattern for *big endian* systems.

Comment: In fact, `BitConverter` is platform dependent: it uses the endianness of the underlying platform. OP's original code, i.e. using manual bit shifts, correctly converts a stream with uints in LSB ordering, no matter what platform it is executed on.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten when you say "it uses the endianness of the underlying platform" that itself mean that it is platform independent. Endianness should be used to decide whether you must shift left or right.